# Recursively check which backed-up folders/files are no longer in source directory

Tags: bash

I have a removable SmartDrive I use as a backup on my CENTOS box like this:

```
sudo cp -r -u -v /SOURCE_FOLDER /media/disk/driveQ/backup/SAME_FOLDER_NAME
```

This works like a charm, giving me the 'latest and greatest', BUT... several folders in the source folder have been removed, renamed, or moved somewhere else within the source folder.  So the backup device is a little more crowded than it needs to be with some folders of a different name containing the same files.

I'm new to bash (started with DOS circa.1983), so need some help with crafting a script that will list folders & files in the backup folder not found anywhere in the source folder, OR files that are physically identical but in different folders.

This is likely a simple task for you bash-saavy folks, and I have done some searching on it, but bash has some pretty obscure flags/methods/piping stuff that I'm not up to speed on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--delete` parameter to `rsync` which will delete destination files that do not exist in the source, more on that in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/delete-extraneous-files-from-dest-dir-via-rsync).  You can use `--update` to do the same thing that `cp -u` would do.  You probably want `--archive` in there too, which enables bunch of other options like being recursive and copying file attributes.

```
rsync --delete --update --archive SOURCE_FOLDER/ SAME_FOLDER_NAME
```

The trailing slash on the source path [is important](http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/01/to-trailing-slash-or-not-to-trailing-slash-to-rsync-path/).  If you want to learn more, [this page](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/using-rsync-to-transfer-and-synchronize-local-and-remote-systems/) is good.  [The man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) never hurts either.  Anther flag maybe worth noting here is `--dry-run` which can help you make sure you're not doing something naughty.

Tl;dr `rsync` is good for local copies with advanced options, not just remote ones

Comment: The trailing slash on `SOURCE_FOLDER/` means **the contents below SOURCE_FOLDER**. Without the slash means **the SOURCE_FOLDER itself**. You can also use the `-n` or `--dry-run` options to **see what will be deleted** before executing the actual delete. I prefer `rsync -uavn --delete` to test and `rsync -uav --delete` to delete. Another useful form is `rsync -uai`.

Comment: I'm no `rsync` whiz, but I think he needs the trailing slash because otherwise he will get `SAME_FOLDER_NAME/SOURCE_FOLDER` when I think he just wants `SAME_FOLDER_NAME`.  Thank you for your other input, it's helpful enough that I will add it to my answer!

Comment: Not saying he doesn't need it, just pointing out what it does. I like your answer.